# ClassNotFound on running (no compilation errors in eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, classnotfoundexception

As I Have described in the title I have a very simple Java Project in eclipse. In the project I have 2 packages:

com.tester.beta.api and 
com.tester.beta.sample

The api package has some classes, and the sample project has only one class with main function:

```
package com.tester.beta.sample;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.tester.beta.api.Analyzer;

public class Example
{

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //I load some files from the hdd
    Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer();

 }

}
```

I have no compilation errors in eclipse - everything seems to be working fine. But when I run the project and when it goes to this line Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer();
I get a ClassNotFound Exception...

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, refreshing the project. restarting eclipse, pc, everything. I tried adding the output folders to the project build path manually - nothing helps. Does any one have an idea what is wrong here? It must be something trivial but I have spent many times on google with no results :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a class not found because the jar file (or folder) containing the `Analyzer` class is not in your classpath.

How are you running the class?

If you are running in command line mode, you have to specify the classpath as follows:

```
java -cp ./path_to_jar Example
```

Comment: I use the eclipse run command. I have also generated a jar file and run it from the command line but it also stops at that point. I tried your approach also but it's the same... Why isn' it in the class path?

Comment: PS: The Analyzer class is part of the project's source code (different package) - I do not load it from a jar file or any other external library...